# Cannot Convert a string representation of a dictionary into an actual dictionary due to an aphostrophe

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I'm trying to convert a string representation of a dictionary into a dictionary in Python. My string contains words that have an apostrophe in them.

```
 d="{'block_num': 1, 'left': 702, 'top': 45, 'width': 62, 'height': 14, 'text': 'won't'}"
```

I want the representation as:

```
 d={'block_num': 1, 'left': 702, 'top': 45, 'width': 62, 'height': 14, 'text': "won't"}
```

But when I try `d = ast.literal_eval(d)` I get the following error:

```
{'block_num': 1, 'left': 702, 'top': 45, 'width': 62, 'height': 14, 'text': 'won't'}
                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm guessing its that apostrophe

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Who or what created the wrong string representation in the first place? I'd fix that instead.

Comment: Use [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) instead of string representation.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
d="{'block_num': 1, 'left': 702, 'top': 45, 'width': 62, 'height': 14, 'text': \"won't\"}"
d = ast.literal_eval(d)
print(d["text"])
# won't
```

If you need something that will handle the original string then you may have to start thinking about regex.